# Custom python install location: tkinter problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. While I have to retain my "main" python install as 2.7.6, I need to install 2.7.9 to be able to use ssl.SSLContext, to get Flask to deal with HTTPS requests.

However, if I just do:

`sudo make install`

or

`sudo make altinstall`

in the Python-2.7.9 directory, I ultimately get:

`make: *** [libinstall] Error 1`

EDIT: this appears at the end of `sudo make install`:

```
...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/saxutils.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmllib.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

So I installed it to a custom directory by modifying the call to `./config`, which did not yield the libinstall error.

However, when I try to import Tkinter into Python 2.7.9 (running from the custom directory) I obtain:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/repos/Python279/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

If I just go ahead and install the vanilla way (i.e., to a non-custom directory) and simply ignore the libinstall error I get, upon importing Tkinter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: unofficial repo for Ubuntu with Python 2.7.x: https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7

Comment: show full error message for "make install". maybe you need some *.h file and you have to install another packet.

Comment: @furas I'm not sure what you mean, but it appears to be the only problem that shows up. See the edited comment. Also, could you explain more about what that repo is exactly?

Comment: this repo gives you precompiled Python 2.7.x and you can install it using `apt-get`

Comment: oh great! will this override my installed `Python 2.7.6`?

Comment: @furas thank you it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas)' suggestion, installing via the 
[Python 2.7 PPA maintained be Felix Krull](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7) worked spectacularly. Thanks Furas!

EDIT Some notes:

1. Because this PPA installs python2.7 (specifically v. 2.7.11, as of 1/29/2016), this obviated the need for a custom python install location
2. While the PPA website mentions that this doesn't include `python-tk`, provided you have installed it, python plays with it just fine (solving my problem)

Comment: There is [repo for Python 3.x](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes) too - the same author.  But you have  to install two modules with `apt-get` - `pythom3.5` and `python3.5-tk`. And [description how to install](http://askubuntu.com/a/682875/177036)

Answer (score 0):

First of all source code from a program must be configured, compiled, then installed. You can do this by:

```
./configure # Or ./config depending on the file name
make
make install
```

Second of all when you tried to import the module `_tkinter` you wanted to import the .py file which was called Tkinter.py
Try to use:

```
import Tkinter
```

Comment: `Tkinter` module probably internally imports `_tkinter` module.

Comment: I did do all those steps (I currently have two separate installs, `./configure` (which raises the `libinstall` error but can still be invoked by typing `python2.7`) and `./configure --prefix /my/custom/install/dir`), and I was indeed importing `Tkinter` which does import `_tkinter` internally.